# Class files are not generated in pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am using the below pom.xml for my application

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>${project.name}</groupId>
<artifactId>${project.name}</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Service_Request</name>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>Prime Repo</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <!-- PrimeFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>


    <!-- EL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <warSourceExcludes>WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</warSourceExcludes>
                <archiveClasses>false</archiveClasses>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But I am unable to generate the class files inside the target directory. Except class files I got everything. My Project Structure is, `Projectname>src>com>...source  files`. I am following the same structure for my other application and I am getting the class files in that. But dont know where I am missing. Even the both `pom.xml` are similar

Comment: You don't need to define src/main/resources, cause it's the convention in Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Your java source files need to go to `src/main/java` by maven convention (not `src`)